# Checkbox preenchido

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

Tenho um script que ao usuário informar o ID são completados os campos: nome e inativo, caso o usuário tenha marcado o checkbox inativo ao se cadastrar retornar o checkbox preenchido e caso não tenha marcado o checkbox retorná-lo sem checked, porém minha função retorna sempre o checkbox preenchido

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    $(document).ready(function(){
            $("input[name='id']").blur(function(){
                    var $nome = $("input[name='nome']");
                    var $inativo = $("input[name='inativo']");

                    $.getJSON('function_pes.php',{ 
                            id: $( this ).val() 
                    },function( json ){
                            $nome.val( json.nome );
                            $inativo.prop('checked', json.inativo );

                    });
            });
    });
```

Comment: Veja se o campo "inativo" do JSON está vindo entre aspas, ex: "true" ou "false". Se estiver entre aspas, quando você faz .prop("checked", json.inativo), ele apenas está checando se o campo "inativo" do JSON existe, o que é sempre verdadeiro, aí o check fica marcado.

Comment: verifiquei em Inspecionar > Network e o meu retorno foi este > {"nome":"THIAGO SILVA","inativo":"0"} mas tenho o retorno checkbox marcado, é realmente o que está acontecendo, poderia me dizer o que fazer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema é que o campo "inativo" do JSON está vindo assim: `"inativo":"0"`. O método .prop("checked", ...) recebe um boolean, então temos que converter esse "0" para boolean primeiro, usando negativa dupla, da seguinte forma:

```
!!1 = true; // negativa dupla em 1 vira verdadeiro
!!0 = false; // negativa dupla em 0 vira falso
```

Porém só isso não é o bastante, porque o valor está como string, então antes convertemos pra int colocando um "+" na frente, então o resultado final fica assim:

```
$inativo.prop('checked', !!+json.inativo );
```

Comment: obrigado, além de sanar a dúvida ainda me ensinou e apontou o erro, grato demais pela ajuda